# access to x-data outside of the scope in alpinejs 3

Tags: alpine.js

I have modalform component made using AlpineJS in topbar of website. When click on SVG icon envelope modalform appears.

```html
<div class="topbar py-2" id="topbar" x-data="topbar()">
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center flex-wrap text-xs p-0 max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8" id="header">
        <div class="address">...</div>
        <div class="worktime">...</div>
        <div class="phone">...</div>
        <div class="relative" @click="openModal = !openModal" x-cloak>
            <x-modules.svg type="envelope-outline" class="h-6 w-6"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--
      Background overlay, show/hide based on modal state.
    -->
    <div x-show="openModal" x-cloak class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity z-50" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
    </div>



    <!-- Modal -->
    <div x-show="openModal" class="fixed z-50 inset-0 overflow-y-auto"
            x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-300"
            x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-50"
            x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100"
            x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
            x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 scale-100"
            x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 scale-50"
            x-cloak
            >

      <div class="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">

        <!-- This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. -->
        <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>

        <!--
          Modal panel, show/hide based on modal state.
        -->
        <div @click.outside="closeModal()" class="inline-block align-bottom rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-headline">

          <form method="POST" action="/modalform" method="POST" @submit.prevent="submitData()">
            @csrf

          <div class="bg-white">
            <div class="modalheader flex place-items-center text-center border-b cursor-pointer text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">
                <h3 class="p-2 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white"    
                    @click="callback = true, zamer = false, eskiz = false"
                    :class="callback ? 'bg-blue-500 text-white' : ''"
                    >
                    Перезвоните мне
                </h3>
                <h3 class="p-2 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white"    
                    @click="callback = false, zamer = true, eskiz = false"
                    :class="zamer ? 'bg-blue-500 text-white' : ''"
                    >
                    Записаться на замер
                </h3>
                <h3 class="p-2 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white"    
                    @click="callback = false, zamer = false, eskiz = true"
                    :class="eskiz ? 'bg-blue-500 text-white' : ''"
                    >
                    Отправить эскиз
                </h3>
                <div class="p-2 place-self-stretch hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white" @click="closeModal()" >
                    <span class="text-3xl">&times;</span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="modalbody flex items-center w-full h-full p-5" 
                x-show="sent"
                x-text="message"
                x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-500"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100"
                x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-200"
                x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 "
                x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 "
                >
            </div>


            <div class="modalbody flex items-start flex-wrap p-5" 
                x-show="!sent"
                x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-500"
                x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 scale-90"
                x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 scale-100"
                x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-200"
                >

              <div class="text-left w-full">

                <div class="mt-2 grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-4 gap-y-2 mb-2">
                    <!-- test --> 
                    <div class="hidden">
                        <x-modules.input type="text" name="test" :value="old('test')" x-model="formData.test" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Name --> 
                    <div class="name" 
                        :class="errorData.name ? 'text-red-500' : ''" 
                        >
                        <x-modules.label for="name" :value="__('auth.user.name')" />
                        <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                            <div class="absolute flex border border-transparent left-0 top-0 h-full w-10" >
                                <x-modules.svg type="user-solid" class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-l bg-gray-100 h-full w-full px-0.5"/>
                            </div>
                            <x-modules.input id="name" class="block w-full pl-12" type="text" name="name" :value="old('name')" x-model="formData.name" placeholder="Введите имя" autofocus />
                        </div>
                        <span x-text="errorData.name" class="text-red-500 text-xs"> </span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Phone -->
                    <div class="phone" 
                        :class="errorData.phone ? 'text-red-500' : ''"
                            >
                        <x-modules.label for="phone" :value="__('auth.user.phone')" />
                        <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                            <div class="absolute flex border border-transparent left-0 top-0 h-full w-10 ">
                                <x-modules.svg type="phone-ringing-outline" class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-l bg-gray-100 h-full w-full px-0.5"/>
                            </div>
                            <x-modules.input id="phone" class="block w-full pl-12" type="text" name="phone" :value="old('phone')" x-model="formData.phone" placeholder="Введите телефон" required autofocus />
                        </div>
                        <span x-text="errorData.phone" class="text-red-500 text-xs"> </span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Email Address -->
                    <div class="email" 
                        x-show="zamer || eskiz" 
                        :class="errorData.email ? 'text-red-500' : ''" 
                            >                
                        <x-modules.label for="email" :value="__('email')" />
                        <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                            <div class="absolute flex border border-transparent left-0 top-0 h-full w-10 ">
                                <x-modules.svg type="envelope-outline" class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-l bg-gray-100 h-full w-full px-0.5"/>
                            </div>
                            <x-modules.input id="email" class="block w-full pl-12" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" x-model="formData.email"  autofocus />
                        </div>
                        <span x-text="errorData.email" class="text-red-500 text-xs"> </span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Address -->
                    <div class="address" 
                        x-show="zamer || eskiz" 
                        :class="errorData.address ? 'text-red-500' : ''"
                            >
                        <x-modules.label for="address" :value="__('auth.user.address')" />
                        <div class="relative text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-800">
                            <div class="absolute flex border border-transparent left-0 top-0 h-full w-10 ">
                                <x-modules.svg type="facade" class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-l bg-gray-100 h-full w-full px-0.5"/>
                            </div>
                            <x-modules.input id="address" class="block w-full pl-12" type="text" name="address" :value="old('address')" x-model="formData.address" autofocus />
                        </div>
                        <span x-text="errorData.address" class="text-red-500 text-xs"> </span>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Upload field -->
                    <div class="upload" x-show="eskiz">
                        <label class="flex items-center justify-evenly p-2 bg-white text-gray-700 rounded-lg shadow-lg border border-gray-300 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white">
                            <x-modules.svg type="upload" class="w-8 h-8"/>
                            <span>Выберите файл</span>
                            <input type="file" class="hidden" multiple />
                        </label>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Message -->
                <div class="message">
                    <x-modules.label for="message" :value="__('auth.user.message')" />
                    <x-modules.textarea rows="2" id="message" class="block w-full" name="message" x-model="formData.message" placeholder="Кратко опишите ваш вопрос"/></textarea>
                    <span x-text="errorData.message" class="text-red-500 text-xs"> </span>
                </div>
                
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modalfooter bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 flex justify-between ">
              <x-modules.button text="Отмена" style="black-outline" class="px-4" @click.prevent="closeModal()" />
              <x-modules.button x-text="buttonLabel" style="blue-solid" class="px-4" @click.prevent="submitData()" />
            </div>

          </div>

          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Modal -->


</div>



    <script>

        function topbar() {
            return {
                mailTooltip: false,
                instagramTooltip: false,
                openModal: false,
                callback: true,
                zamer: false,
                eskiz: false,

                formData: {
                  test: '',
                  name: '',
                  phone: '',
                  email: '',
                  address: '',
                  message: '',
                  _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                },

                message: '',
                responseData: [],
                errorStates: {
                  name: false,
                  phone: false,
                  email: false,
                  address: false,
                  message: false
                },
                errorData: [],
                loading: false,
                sent: false,
                buttonLabel: 'Отправить',


                resetFields() {
                    this.formData.test = '',
                    this.formData.name = '',
                    this.formData.phone = '',
                    this.formData.email = '',
                    this.formData.address = '',
                    this.formData.message = ''
                },


                closeModal() {
                    this.openModal = false;
                    this.callback = false;
                    this.zamer = false;
                    this.eskiz = false;
                },


                submitData() {
                    // проверка от ботов вместо капчи
                    // если бот что-то заполнил в поле test, то останавливаем работу функции
                    // и не отправляем письмо
                    // что-то нихуя не работает
                    if (this.formData.test.length != 0) {
                        this.closeModal();
                        return false;
                    };

                    axios.post('/modalform', this.formData)
                    .then( (response) => {
                        this.buttonLabel = 'Отправляем...';
                        this.loading = true;
                        console.log(response);
                        this.resetFields();
                        this.sent = true;
                        this.message = 'Сообщение успешно отправлено!';
                        this.responseData = response.data;
                    })

                    .then( () => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.sent = false;
                        this.closeModal();
                        this.buttonLabel = 'Отправить';
                        this.message = '';
                    })

                    .catch( (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        this.message = 'Ooops! Что-то пошло не так!'
                        this.errorData = error.response.data.errors;
                        this.isErrorName();
                    });
                },

                isErrorName() {
                    if (error.response.data.errors.name === 'undefined') {
                        this.errorStates.name = false;
                    } else {
                        this.errorStates.name = true;
                    }
                },


            }

        }

    </script>
```

Code above allows to open modalform only if click on the button located inside div, which contains `x-data="topbar()"`.
Then I have following code in head section of my website to allow open modalform from anywhere of website.

```html
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>;

    window.contactForm = function(){
        document.getElementById('topbar').__x.$data.openModal = true;
        document.getElementById('topbar').__x.$data.callback = true;
    };
</script>
```

Now I can open modal form from anywhere like that

```html
<div class="callback">
  <span @click="contactForm()">call me back</span>
</div>
```

But after upgrading to AlpineJS 3 it doesn't work anymore. How to do the same in  Alpine 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach to access the data property from the component itself is a quite hacky approach. A good way to tackle this without having to dig into the internal objects of Alpine (which could change any time without notice) is to use events.

So what you would essentially do is to add an event handler to the modal (or anywhere else on the page within your topbar component)

```html
<div x-show="openModal" class="fixed z-50 inset-0 overflow-y-auto"
        @open-modal.window="openModal = true; callback = true"
        ...
        x-cloak
        >
```

and then just fire the event any time you wish to open the modal anywhere outside of the component like this:

```html
<div class="callback">
  <span @click="$dispatch('open-modal')">call me back</span>
</div>
```

You can of course also pass parameters to the event if you need more customization, e.g. a specific title. See the docs on [dispatch](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/dispatch) and [events](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on) for details.

#### Alternative ways

In AlpineJS 3, you have additional ways to achieve this. Unlike AlpineJS 2, nested components have full access to parent component data.

As I see that you are actually using @click on your span element opening the modal, you seem to have some kind of component around it. If this component is located somewhere within your topbar component, opening the modal is as easy as:

```html
<div class="callback">
  <span @click="openModal = true; callback = true">call me back</span>
</div>
```

A third way would be to register a [$store](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) and storing the modal conditional there. But this could quickly get confusing, so I wouldn't recommend that approach.